# Updating Records on Zoho using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, criteria, insert-update, zoho

I am trying to update records on a Zoho database and there does not seem to be a single piece of C# code online for me to use to help find my issue. My code is:

```cs
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://creator.zoho.com/api/v2/[group name]/[app name]/report/[report name]?criteria="
                + "(ID == " + log.ID);
request.Method = "PATCH";
string accessCode = Database.getAccess();
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Zoho-oauthtoken " + accessCode);

var time = DateTime.UtcNow;
TimeZoneInfo easternZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
var easternTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(time, easternZone).ToString("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss");

JObject dataJson = new JObject();
JObject requestObject = new JObject();
JArray dataArray = new JArray();

dataJson.Add("Log_Out", easternTime);

dataArray.Add(dataJson);
requestObject.Add("data", dataArray);
JObject requestBody = requestObject;

string dataString = requestBody.ToString();
var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dataString);
int dataLength = data.Length;
request.ContentType = "application/json";
request.ContentLength = dataLength;
using (var writer = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    writer.Write(data, 0, dataLength);
}

WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
string responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
JObject ResponseJSON = JObject.Parse(responseString);
Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ResponseJSON));
}
```

It says that criteria is required when it gives me an error message but I have the criteria in the URL. If anybody knows of a solution it would be appreciated since there is not a single example or answer to this anywhere online that is using C# without the SDK stuff, which I am not supposed to use.

Comment: We have no idea which API you are trying to use, at least point to the docs, give us a small clue.

Answer (score 0):

In case anybody has the same question I will post the answer I found after a long time of not finding anything useful. You need to put the criteria in the requestBody JObject I had such that it says
`requestBody.Add("criteria", "ID == " + log.ID);`
under where you declare requestBody.